# Extracting a portion of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

What I have in mind is the following:

- Load web page
- Find two *div*s with specific class names
- Extract the content of everything in between, except of the last *div*

The reason I'm asking for it to extract anything in between is that the most important *div* I need doesn't have a class name assigned.

EDIT: Here's some generic code of what the page looks like:

```
<div class="text1">
    <p><b>Text 1.1</b><br>
    <b>Text 1.2</b></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Text without class which I also need.</p>
</div>
<div class="enddiv">
    [content of enddiv]
</div>
```

I need everything in between the divs *text1* and *enddiv*, but **not** the contents of *enddiv*.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are you trying to archive? are trying to crawl a webpage? this question as-is is too broad and unsuitable for stackoverflow, please edit it and try to be more specific

Comment: Are you trying to do this on your own page with javascript? if you can please post an example

Comment: What you're trying to do is called [screen scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping).  Q: Do you know any programming languages?  For example, would you be interested in doing this with NodeJS and Javascript?  If so, look [here](https://codeburst.io/an-introduction-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-1045b55c63f7) or [here](https://medium.com/data-scraper-tips-tricks/scraping-data-with-javascript-in-3-minutes-8a7cf8275b31).  Otherwise, look here: https://www.scrapehero.com/top-free-and-paid-web-scraping-tools-and-software/

Comment: I don't know any programming languages, so thanks for the link... I should really learn one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome DeBedenHasen, If I understood you well you can do something like this:

```
// Select all elements from .text1 and so on
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.text1, .text1 ~ *')

let string = '' // content will go here

// Store all content before reach .enddiv
for (const e of elements)
  if (e.getAttribute('class')  == 'enddiv') break
  else string += e.textContent

// Print the content
document.body.innerHTML = string
```

Here you can check your example: https://jsfiddle.net/s4mv5c1b/

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

var selectedDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.className');

Comment: Thanks. That would help with the divs that have class names assigned. As I said, one of the divs I need doesn't. There are more than one of those however. Is it even possible to get the content of that one?